# Cannot declare template typed actor in C++ Actor Framework

Tags: c++, c++11, actor, c++-actor-framework

I'm trying to declare a strongly-typed actor in [C++ actor framework (CAF)](http://actor-framework.org), but my code doesn't compile for some reason. Could you tell me what's wrong with it?

```
#include "caf/all.hpp"

template <typename TNum>
class DiscoverRequest {};

template <typename TNum>
class DiscoverResponse {};

template <typename TNum>
class DataRequest {};

template <typename TNum>
class DataResponse {};

template <typename TNum>
using BlockActor = caf::typed_actor<
    /* ERROR NEXT LINE */
    caf::replies_to<DiscoverRequest<TNum>>::with<DiscoverResponse<TNum>>,
    caf::replies_to<DataRequest<TNum>>    ::with<DataResponse<TNum>> >;
```

The error message:

```
Block.hh:13:71: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template
parameter list for 'template<class ... Sigs> class caf::typed_actor'

caf::replies_to<DiscoverRequest<TNum>>::with<DiscoverResponse<TNum>>,
                                                                  ^
Block.hh:13:71: error: expected a type, got   
'(caf::replies_to<DiscoverRequest<TNum> >::with < <expression error>)'
```

But if I replace `DiscoverRequest<TNum>` and `DiscoverResponse<TNum>` with specific instantiations, like, for example, `DiscoverRequest<float>`, it does compile nicely. So, I think something in CAF internals forbids using such a construct.

My compiler is GCC G++ 4.9.2 (with `-std=c++11`, of course), running on Fedora 21. The CAF is the [latest revision](https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/commit/d9e99842449752ec777beca1c21aff1c45a5008b) of its `master` branch, linked to the project as a Git submodule.

Comment: I think it misses `template` keyword, try `caf::replies_to<DiscoverRequest<TNum>>::template with<DiscoverResponse<TNum>>`

Comment: See [where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: @Jarod42: `typename caf::replies_to<DiscoverRequest<TNum>>::template with<DiscoverResponse<TNum>>` seems to work, thanks for the idea! You should turn your comment into an answer so I could approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template` keyword is missing.

It should be

```
template <typename TNum>
using BlockActor = caf::typed_actor<
    typename caf::replies_to<DiscoverRequest<TNum>>::template with<DiscoverResponse<TNum>>,
    typename caf::replies_to<DataRequest<TNum>>    ::template with<DataResponse<TNum>> >;
```

Comment: It turns out it has to have `typename` keyword too: `typename caf::replies ... `

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Jarod42 is correct to get this to compile. However, I wonder why you don't follow the more idiomatic way for defining interfaces with atom constants:

```
using discover_request_atom = atom_constant<atom("DiscoverRq")>;

using discover_response_atom = atom_constant<atom("DiscoverRs")>;

using data_request_atom = atom_constant<atom("DataRq")>;

using data_response_atom = atom_constant<atom("DataRs")>;

template <class TNum>
using BlockActor = caf::typed_actor<
    replies_to<discover_request_atom, TNum>::with<discover_response_atom, TNum>,
    replies_to<data_request_atom, TNum>    ::with<data_response_atom, TNum>>;
```

This safes you a lot of headache later on, as it safes you from announcing each and every one of your template instances.

Comment: It could well be that @firegurafiku wants to beef up the currently empty structs later on. But if that's not the case, this looks certainly much cleaner.

Comment: @neverlord: Thanks for showing the way how to declare tuple messages in typed actor interfaces, I didn't get it from the reading of the manual.

Comment: @matthias-vallentin: Yes, the structs are empty currently. Here I try to abstract from exact messages structures, this is why I use custom classes. But may be atom-based approach would be better, I'm not sure.